# MySQL workbench database import from Azure SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, mysql-workbench

I am currently trying to use the MySQL Workbench migration wizard to import a database located on an Azure SQL Managed instance to an on-premise MySQL server, but i have an issue with the wizard: it fails to retrieve the database schema with the following error:

'**WARNING: The following catalogs were not found: database_name'**

Note: The user i currently use to perform the migration is actually granted on VIEW DEFINITION at the database level but not at the server level (VIEW ANY DEFINITION) , since it is not supported in Azure SQL. Any idea about how to make this wizard work is welcomed.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the Managed Instance with that user through SQL Server Management Studio and view everything?  I'd validate the security of the account itself first before troubleshooting the migration wizard.  I'd also try the Visual Studio tools as an alternative.

Comment: Hi @WintermeW, is the error solved now?

Answer (score 0):

Like @JeffRamos said before you using MySQL Workbench migration,  please check if the user can connect to the Azure SQL Managed instance with SSMS and has the permission to access the Azure MI database. Just from the error message, it's not the firewall issue.

As I know about Azure Managed instance, if we want migrate the database, the user muse be db_owner or admin account.

HTH.